# Pushing banner to the bottom of the row but making it responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm using Foundation to style my website. Currently I have an image filling up a content and a panel that overlaps the bottom of the image. (Because of the padding-top). However, when the screen gets smaller the padding-top pushes the panel far too down and it creates a big gap between the image and the panel, where as, I would like the panel to be directly underneath the image instead of overlaying.

What's a better way to achieve the same thing, while making it more mobile friendly?

```
<div class='row'>
<%= content_for :header do %>
  <div id='headerwrap'>

    <div class='homepage'>
      <div class="panel large-12 columns">
        <div class="small-12 medium-9 columns">
          <h2>Beta test our games for free</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
          <input type="text" id="right-label" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

My css file looks like this.

```
#headerwrap { backgroundimage:url('http://www.nordplusonline.org/var/ezwebin_site/storage/images/media/images/frontpage_topslide/horizontal/22047-1-eng-GB/horizontal.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  text-align: right;
  height: 600px;
}

.homepage {
  padding-top: 500px;
}
```

Comment: post a fiddle or link to the test site.

Comment: Try using a percentage instead of a static pixel amount.

Comment: I tried the percentage. It works initially, but when the frame gets resized, the bottom banner seems to float to the middle of the image.